# In laravel blade, can't access array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array collection that is coming from my controller as follows

```
$this->dailyStandupMomList = ProjectDailyStandupMomList::with('dailyStandupMomBlockerAssignments')->where('mom_id', $id)->get();
```

when I view my `dailyStandupMom` array  with `{{dailyStandupMom[0]}}` form the blade, I see one of the objects as follows

```
    {...
    "id": 27,
    "mom_id": 14,
    "task_id": 948,
    ...
    "daily_standup_mom_blocker_assignments": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "mom_list_id": 27,
            "assigned_to": 36,
            "blocker_assigned_to": {
                "id": 36,
                "name": "Aakash Joshi",
                ...
         }
      ],
      ...}
```

but when I do `object->daily_standup_mom_blocker_assignments`, it gives me nothing; therefore, I could not do a for each on it.

Please help.

Comment: do you access it like this? dailyStandupMom[0]->daily_standup_mom_blocker_assignments

Comment: @aliSafaei , Yes, but it is giving me nothing.

Comment: put this on ur blade : {{dd(dailyStandupMom[0])}}   , and tell what's the result

Comment: @alisafaei. I can see a json object as described above but I just could not access the array. it is as if it doesn't exist when I try to access it.

Comment: have you tried `$object->dailyStandupMomBlockerAssignments` ? as that would be the dynamic property for the relationship ... relationship names become snake cased by default when serialized

Comment: I changed `dailyStandupMomBlockerAssignments` to `daily_standup_mom_blocker_assignments` in the model and it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your array is a string so you get nothing
You can change your casts variable or use mutators
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: if it was a string, why can't I see it with `{{...}}` ?

Comment: Can you access object->id ?

Comment: Yes I can, that is what is confusing me... I can access some properties

Comment: check that you wrote correct "daily_standup_mom_blocker_assignments"

Comment: I have copied and pasted it form the `dailyStandupMom[0]`...

Comment: copy here full code